# (Android) Getting settings from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity (first) that starts a new activity (second). If I returned to my first activity, I want to get some settings I've set at the second activity, without saving in SharedPreferences (just temporary).
Is there a way to get public attributes of my second activity?
How can I do that on the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you can get information returned from the second activity is to invoke it with `startActivityForResult`.

From Android documentation:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then, in `Activity1` override this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CREATE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //ACT
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's a link to referring documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Hope it helps.

Comment: described here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: I have seen this on one link...

resultIntent = new Intent(null);
resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, enteredTextValue);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();         
But I can't call "finish()", I haven't something like a "OK"-Button or "Close". I have a ListView where i can check items and after that I push the back button on my Smartphone. Then i want to add my checked items in a list in my first activity.

Comment: Is there any event or Listener to react when I push "back" on my Smartphone ?